# Hosting dotnet core 6 MVC App with docker and Nginx using a VPS

Tags: docker, nginx, .net-core, vps

I'm using a vps (virtual private server) with linux ubuntu, docker, and Nginx. I'm trying to host multiple dotnet core 6 MVC apps, but it doesn't works well.

After I created the docker image (docker build) I ran the container using the command below:

```
docker run --rm -p 5000:5000 -p 5001:5001 --name ContainerNAme 
imagename
```

docker ps:

[image]

NGINX CONFIG

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <MY VPS IP ADRRESS HERE>;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:5001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
    }
```

When I try to access the address

```
http://<MY VPS IP ADRRESS HERE>
```

or

```
http://<MY VPS IP ADRRESS HERE>:5001
```

The error 502 (Bad Gateway) shows.

Afer run the docker run command inside VPS:
[image]

Running the app in my localmachine:
[image]